# Calling @classmethod decorated method throws a TypeError

Tags: python, static-methods, read-eval-print-loop, class-method

I am trying to figure out difference between `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod`. The latter is passed a `cls` instance.

When I tried to call the `@classmethod`, it is giving me an error.

How should I call a `@classmethod` (`to_c()` and `to_f()`) decorated method in REPL?

Here is the REPL calls

```
>>> from temperature_converter import *
>>> c = TemperatureConverter(41)
>>> TemperatureConverter.to_f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Repos\Python\module-3\temperature_converter.py", line 21, in to_f
    return cls.c_to_f(cls.temperature)
  File "C:\Repos\Python\module-3\temperature_converter.py", line 25, in c_to_f
    return celsius * 9 / 5 + 32
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'property' and 'int'
```

Here is the class, `TemperatureConverter`

```
class TemperatureConverter:
    _temperature = 0

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        return self._temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        self._temperature = value

    def __init__(self, temperature):
        self.temperature = temperature

    @classmethod
    def to_c(cls):
        return cls.f_to_c(cls.temperature)

    @classmethod
    def to_f(cls):
        return cls.c_to_f(cls.temperature)

    @staticmethod
    def c_to_f(celsius):
        return celsius * 9 / 5 + 32

    @staticmethod
    def f_to_c(fahrenheit):
        return (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9
```

Comment: What you're trying to do makes no sense. `cls.temperature` refers to the descriptor object itself, not to an instance that has a value. Neither class methods nor static methods can possibly access any instance value.

Comment: Why do you want `to_c` and `to_f` to be classmethods? The temperature they're likely want to be converting (if you don't change their definition to give them an argument) is the `_temperature` instance attribute, since the class attribute of that name will always be `0`. There's really no need for the class attribute, even as a default value, since very instance gets a value assigned by the constructor (via the property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**: You trying to access the `temperature` property from the class and expecting the same result as an instance, in this case an `int` value of `41`.  However, attributes are called differently in instances and classes. Compare the `__get__` method for each:

**Description**

```
# Reassignments for illustration
C = TemperatureConverter                                   # class  
i = c                                                      # instance 
attr = "temperature"                                       # attribute    

# Call via Instance binding, `c.temperature`
C.__dict__[attr].__get__(i, C)                     
# 41

# Call via Class binding, `C.temperature`
C.__dict__[attr].__get__(None, C)                      
# <property at 0x4ab9458>
```

Here is more [information](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) on the signature of the `__get__`  method and a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3681323/4531270) on how descriptors work.  In this case, the signature is could be seen as `C.__get__(self, inst, cls)`.  In short, when getting from a property, **unlike an instance calls, calls from a class passes `None` for the instance argument**.

As shown above, the property object is returned if bound to the class:

```
C.temperature
# <property at 0x4ab9458>
```

Can we still "get" the value from the property object?  Let us call `__get__` on the property object:

```
C.temperature.__get__(i, C)
# 41
```

The latter shows it is possible to get the property value while bound to a class.  While it may be tempting to implement the `__get__` method on `cls.temperature` inside your class method, *you still need to pass in an instance* (e.g. `i`) to access the value of the property.  Instances are not accessible in a class method.  Therefore, we see why the property object is returned in your code, which is trying to multiply with an `int` and raises the error you observe.

This is one explanation for your problem, in particular describing why you cannot access your property value `cls.temperature` within a class method.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought an `instance` of a class object was being passed to `to_c(cls)` via `cls`. I was wrong... Thanks, @pylang for the enlightment