# Why @property broke synchronizing with source object on proxy class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a proxy in Python because of function and attributes access (something like private). I create the proxy with references to functions in the source object. But I have a problem, that functions have no problem with changing attributes but property yes. Here is an example:

**A working example**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.get_value = cls.get_value
        # del cls

a = A()
p = Proxy(a)

print(a.get_value(), p.get_value())
a.value = 2
print(a.get_value(), p.get_value())
```

Output:

```
1 1
2 2
```

**Not working:**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1

    @property
    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.get_value = cls.get_value
        # del cls

a = A()
p = Proxy(a)

print(a.get_value, p.get_value)
a.value = 2
print(a.get_value, p.get_value)
```

Output:

```
1 1
2 1
```

Can someone explain me where the problem is and if there is any solution for this? I could use functions, but I think @property is more Python solution. And I really want to know what is the difference. Thank you

Comment: Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681272/can-i-get-a-reference-to-a-python-property) might help you understand and solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

In `Proxy.__init__`, you end up executing:

```
self.get_value = a.get_value
```

and very different things happen in your two examples.

In the first case, `a.get_value` is a method of `a`. So, calling `p.get_value()` is the same as calling `a.get_value()`. You get identical results.

In the second case, you have already defined `a.get_value` as a property, so `self.get_value = a.get_value` is basically `self.get_value = 2`, it is just an `int` attribute of `p`.