# Python, how to assign an @property method to another class' instance

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance

I'm trying to merge two instances of two different classes.
One idea that could work for me is to assign the attributes from class `b` to an existing instance of class `a`. Normally I would let `a` inherit from `b` but this is not possible because `a` is initialized when `b` is still unknown.

Obviously this is a dummy example, but i think it reflects my problem.

```
class aa:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.c = 'c'

class bb:
    def __init__(self, obj) -> None:
        obj.get_c = self.get_c
        self.c = 3
    
    @property
    def get_c(self):
        return self.c

a=aa()
b=bb(a)
```

Is it possible to copy the method `get_c` that it returns `a.c` when `a.get_c` is called and not whatever  value `b.c` had when`b` was initialized?

Desired Output:

```
a.get_c -> 'c'
b.get_c -> 3
```

Comment: *"when a.get_c is called"* `a` does not have a `get_c` method, so the answer is no

Comment: @DeepSpace That's what he's trying to find out how to do -- he wants to give `a` a `get_c` property by copying it from `b`.

Comment: @Barmar I see, but why not just implement it on `a` to begin with?

Comment: This might be a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681272/can-i-get-a-reference-to-a-python-property

Comment: @Yehla This feels like an XY problem. See my previous comment. Why are you not defining the property in `aa`?

Comment: I tried to do that but it references to yet another class' property which is still `None` at the creation of `b` so it's actually not `self.c` but `self.another_class.c`. And then it still copies the None instead of the later value.